# i wanna Extract image address in Laravel controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, src

I want to extract image url address in Laravel controller

For example:

```php
$value = "p tag this is a test end p tag div tag class=myClass this is a test end div tag img tag src='http://www.google.com/1.jpg' end img tag"
```

I want to get this string 'http://www.google.com/1.jpg' in controller.

My Laravel version is 7.x

Answer (score 0):

use laravel helpers

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$value = "p tag this is a test end p tag div tag class="myClass">this is a teste end div tag img tag src="http://www.google.com/1.jpg" />

$slice = Str::between($value, 'src="', '/>');